# Mongodb - Map-Reduce - Complete data is not returned

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am using Map Reduce. The problem is that if the no. input of documents is > 100, then I am not getting the expected no. of results but if the no. of input documents is <= 100, then I am getting the results as expected.

**Sample output that I am getting:**

```
{
    "_id" : "5504",
    "value" : [
            ObjectId("51c921bae4b0f0f776b339d2"),
            ObjectId("51b06b5be4b021e44bc69755")
    ]
}
```

**Problem:** If there are <= 100 documents for user (id:5504), then I am getting that many no. of ids in the output array but if the no. of documents >100, then I am getting very few ids in the output array. I got the above output when the no. of documents for this user was 101, but when it was 100, I got 100 ids. Why this strange behaviour and what's the solution for this?

**Map Function:**

```
db.system.js.save({

    _id: "map1",

    value: function () {
        var value = {
            "data": [{
                "_id": this._id,
                "creation_time": this.creation_time
            }]
        };
        emit(this.user_id, value);
    }
});
```

**Reduce Function:**

```
db.system.js.save({

    _id: "reduce1",

    value: function (key, values) {
        var reducedValue = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            reducedValue.push({
                "_id": values[i].data[0]._id,
                "creation_time": values[i].data[0].creation_time
            });
        }
        return {
            data: reducedValue
        };
    }
});
```

**Finalize Function:**

```
db.system.js.save({

    _id: "finalize1",

    value: function (key, reducedValue) {
        var a = reducedValue.data.sort(compare1);
        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            ids.push(a[i]._id);
        }
        return ids;
    }
});
```

**Compare Function:**

```
db.system.js.save({

    _id: "compare1",

    value: function (a, b) {
        if (a.creation_time < b.creation_time) return 1;
        if (a.creation_time > b.creation_time) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

**MapReduce() call**

```
db.notifications.mapReduce(map1, reduce1, {out: "notifications_result", query: {delivered:true, user_id:"5504"}, finalize: finalize1});
```

Comment: I think that this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318791/mapreduce-results-seem-limited-to-100

Comment: and this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896349/what-is-wrong-with-this-map-reduce-query-on-mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MongoDB could call reduce function many times, you must ensure [Function Idempotence](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-reduce-function/#ensure-reduce-function-idempotence). A little modification on your reduce function solves the problem:

```
db.system.js.save({

    _id: "reduce1",

    value: function (key, values) {
        var reducedValue = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < values[i].data.length; j++) {
                reducedValue.push({
                    "_id": values[i].data[j]._id,
                    "creation_time": values[i].data[j].creation_time
                });   
            }

        }
        return {
            data: reducedValue
        };
    }
});
```

Note that now the `values[i].data`array is traversed too, because the return of other `reduce1` calls [are in the `values` array](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function).

Comment: also asked and answered here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/EhNEbyB9UBA/YgwELC3e91sJ